Viewing a 3D object from inside
I have a list of coordinates in 3D all of which lie on the surface of a unit sphere (for all intents and purpose these are just random points on the sphere).
I want to view them as from the centre of the sphere and be able to rotate the view using the mouse. When I set ViewPoint to {0,0,0} (the centre of the sphere) it looks OK but when I use the mouse to rotate it the view is messed up. It looks like the image is rotating about some other point, but I can't work out which and how to correct it. Essentially I want the view to rotate about the origin as though standing at the centre of the sphere and looking around (imagine standing on the Earth and looking around at the night sky - that would be a suitable analogy).
The code I have is:
ListPointPlot3D[coords, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 0}]

Where "coords" is a list of the 3D coordinates of the points.


Use ViewVector

coords = RandomPoint[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 2}], 500];
ListPointPlot3D[coords, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ViewVector -> {0, 0, 0}]

coords = RandomPoint[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 2}], 500];
Show[ListPointPlot3D[coords, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ViewVector -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Medium], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ coords[[1 ;; 10]]}], 
 ViewVector -> {1, 1, 1}]



Another example is

ContourPlot3D[
 x^2/5^2 + y^2/4^2 + z^2/3^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
  ViewVector -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.3], Thick}]



Thank you, yes, that seems to do the trick. I thought I had tried this, but I think my previous efforts had reset viewing points etc and I needed to set back to default.
